# SEND OBJECT isn't available for one User in a Spilt-database

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have one User getting an error message in a MS ACCESS split database. The message is "The command or action "Send Object" isn't available now." The User gets this message when they are clicking on a command button that is suppose to open GroupWise e-mail and copy text from a MSACCESS form and have the TO: FROM: and SUBJECT: lines auto-populate.
 I looked at the USER's Internet Explorer settings.
 I checked to see if the USER has the most recent MS JET 4.0
 I provided another copy of the front-end to save to the desktop
All other Users are not experiencing this problem. I must also add that this specific User was recently upgraded to MS OFFICE 2010, like the rest of us... Any suggestions ?  Thanks

Comment: Could this be a 32-bit vs 64-bit Office issue? Specifically, could all other users be running the 32-bit version of Office 2010 and this one user is running the 64-bit version?

Comment: I will check with it out..

Comment: No... that is not it.. I check the version of the USER with issues and several others. We all have 32 bit.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? It affects a handful of users none of whom seem to connected in any way. I can't reproduce the problem in my environment either.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone passing by on Google, this worked for me. The affected users had recently upgraded to Windows 7 with 32-bit Office 2010 (although some had upgraded without issue). It also works on my local machine (Windows 7 with 64-bit Office 2010).

Instead of using `DoCmd.SendObject(....)`:

```
Sub SendMail()

Dim myOb As Object
Dim AutoSend as boolean

Set myOb = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMail = myOb.CreateItem(olMailItem)

//Set whether to send email automatically or make user press Send
AutoSend = False

With oMail
    .Body = "Message text"
    .Subject = "Subject line"
    .To = To@example.com
    .cc = cc@example.com

    If AutoSend Then
        .send
    Else
        .display
    End If
End With

    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```